# Horizontal dashed line on page break in listings environment

Tags: listings, page-breaking, rules

Well, the title says it all. I have code scripts that span over multiple pages. Is it possible to display a dashed line at the bottom and/or top of the page in which the `listings` environment experience a page break, and keep the solid line at the very top and very bottom of the environment?

A screen dump illustrating my question is given below. I would like to add dashed lines where the `listings` environment break.

[image]

I use `mcode` in combination with the `listings` enivorment, providing a set of `lstset` parameters. The following MWE illustrates where I would prefer to have horizontal, dashed lines, avoiding that the `lstlistings` environment just breaks to white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mcode, listings}
\definecolor{cornsilk}{RGB}{255,248,220}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Something}

The following code is just a really long list of comments, really. 

\begin{lstlisting}
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % It would be nice with a horisontal dashed line below me. 
    % Another dashed above me, too.
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a MWE of what you have got.

Comment: Normally I would close this question but the bounty avoids it. Your question is similar to `do it for me` because you didn't provide a mwe. Do you use any related packages?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Affirmative! Updated.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To draw such a frame you should use an other package which allows such modifications. The default packages are [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). In the example below I provided a solution using `tcolorbox` whereby a new listings environment `lstmcode` is defined. Please note that I am using the version 2.22 for the example below.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mcode, listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mymcode}{%
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont\footnotesize,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\color{gray}\fontfamily{pcr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  belowskip=0pt,
 aboveskip=0pt,
}

\definecolor{cornsilk}{RGB}{255,248,220}

\usepackage[breakable,listings,skins,hooks]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{lstmcode}{%
 breakable,
 colback=cornsilk,
 listing options={style=mymcode},
 listing only,
 enhanced,
 overlay first app={%
   \draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=1pt] (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west);%
  },
 overlay middle app={%
   \draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=-1pt] (frame.north east) -- (frame.north west);
   \draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=1pt] (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west);%
  },
 overlay last app={%
   \draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=-1pt] (frame.north east) -- (frame.north west);
  },
}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Something}

The following code is just a really long list of comments, really. 

\begin{lstmcode}
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % It would be nice with a horisontal dashed line below me. 
    % Another dashed above me, too.
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
\end{lstmcode}

\end{document}
```

---

Here an other approach using `mdframed`. The output is equal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mcode, listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mymcode}{%
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont\footnotesize,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\color{gray}\fontfamily{pcr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  belowskip=0pt,
 aboveskip=0pt,
}

\definecolor{cornsilk}{RGB}{255,248,220}



\mdfdefinestyle{mcode}{%
 roundcorner=5pt,
 skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=10pt,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,
 backgroundcolor=cornsilk,
 firstextra={\draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=1pt] (O) -- (P|-O);},
 secondextra={\draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=-1pt] (O|-P) -- (P);},
 middleextra={\draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=1pt] (O) -- (P|-O);\draw[dashed,line width=1pt,xshift=-1pt] (O|-P) -- (P);},
}
\lstnewenvironment{lstmcode}
 {\lstset{style=mymcode}}{}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=mcode]{lstmcode}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Something}

The following code is just a really long list of comments, really. 

\begin{lstmcode}
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % It would be nice with a horisontal dashed line below me. 
    % Another dashed above me, too.
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
    % Matlab code 
\end{lstmcode}

\end{document}
```